# Программы не имеют доступ в сеть, Avast, DropBox, GoogleDrive В чем может быть причина?

Tags: windows, сеть, dropbox

Браузеры, мэсенджеры нормально выходят в сеть.
На примере Avast: если сетевой кабель не подключен вообще или еще не успело установится соединение то хотябы немного думает перед тем как выдать ошибку:

The online content is unavailable
Please, check your internet connection and try again.

если соединение в норме для других приложений то сразу выдает ошибку не задумываясь ни на мгновение.

Браудмамаман (язык сломаешь) винды отключен, стоит от Comodo, отключаю. Выключаю также из автозапуска.

1. что пробовал:

   1. Переустанавливал DropBox, установка идет, качает из инета данные но
      при запуске уже в трэе пишет что уже интернета не видит
   2. Пробовал выйти в сеть через другой интернет (мобильный) то же самое
   3. Просмотрел список задач на предмет наличия странных процесов, поубивал лишнее
   4. Загрузился в минимальном режиме msconfig->Диагностический запуск
   5. Запустил все чинилки из утилиты NetAdapterRepair1.2.exe . тоесть сброс DNS, hosts и многое другое стандартное
   6. удалил все лишние адаптеры сетевые, переустановил нужный
   7. включил обратно стандартный Брандмауэр
   8. Установил DropBox на другой комп и успешно авторизировался и засинронил файлы через ту же сеть, тоесть проблема точно в настройках проблемного компа а не в сети

Видимо эти приложения используют какойто нестандартный метод подключения

В списке подключений есть подключения от DropBox, от avast нету

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Trace одного из подключений :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте удалить avast и главное сопутствующие программы, avast это хороший в прошлом, но по моему не хороший сегодня антивирус, из бесплатных лучше bitdefender